# how to use android database in/as a phonegap database

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I want to use android database into same phonegap apps.

more descripation:

I created phonegap application, but phonegap application is not supporting services so, we have created application that in java for android and will create for iPhone also.

But the problem is that i need to check store data into android(.java) for service. but how can we use that database into phonegap(.javascript)

sorry for my grammar.

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#openDatabase

Comment: i have done this part in phonegap but i need to use database from android created sqlite.

Comment: your old app is phonegap/java?

Comment: is in phonegap but i used java(android) for service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write phonegap plugins for same. Please refer [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [persistenceJS](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs) will fit your need

Comment: can you able to give me example.?